# How can I display a widget for each item in an array?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a mini-app where it lists a bunch of restaurants.
How would I get this code to work:

```
class MainBottom extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (var i = 0; i < resNames.length; i++) {
            RestaurantItem(resNames[i], resLocations[i]);
          }
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get the error `The element type 'Set<RestaurantItem>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'` at `for (var i = 0; i < resNames.length; i++)`, and the error:`Expected to find '}'` at `RestaurantItem(resNames[i], resLocations[i]);`

PS, the widget `RestaurantItem` is a stateless one

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `{}` means you are declaring a `Set` in your `Widget tree`, Read more about `Sets` here: [Sets in Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#sets)

You can fix this by removing the `{}`. I added a demo using your code as example:

```
class MainBottom extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (var i = 0; i < resNames.length; i++) // remove the brackets
            RestaurantItem(resNames[i], resLocations[i]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but it only works when you remove the semicolon too :)

Comment: Didn't catch that, I updated my answer. @SquigglyHl

Comment: I'll mark this as a correct answer once the stackoverflow lets me

Comment: Cool mate, Happy Fluttering :)